# Django how to compare stored hash password and plain password

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I created function to allow admin to create users accounts. I used a password generator + make_password() function to hash the password.

Now it's sending the plain password to users email and storing it in the database hashed.

now the user is able to login with the hashed password only.

my view.py:

```
@admin_login_required
def add_emp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.POST['user_name']
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_otj = request.POST['user_otj']
        user_password = pwo.generate()
        user_password1 = make_password(user_password)
        empObj = User.objects.create(user_name=user_name, user_email=user_email, user_password=user_password1, user_otj=user_otj)
        if empObj:
            subject = 'Login Info'
            message = f'Name : {user_name}, \n Email : {user_email}, \n Password : {user_password} \n FROM - AA Portal'
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, [user_email])
            messages.success(request, "Employee was added successfully!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create-emp')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Some error was occurred!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create-emp')
    return render(request, 'AddEmp.html')

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_password = request.POST['user_password']
        user_details = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).values()
        hashed_pw = User.objects.all().first().user_password
        checkpass = check_password(user_password, hashed_pw)

        if user_details and checkpass:
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['user_email'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['u_id'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['user_name'] = user_details[0]["user_name"]
            request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_email = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    user_role_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_avatar_path = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user_job_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_educ_qual = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_companies = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
```

Any idea how to make the user login with the plain password and keep it hashed in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers) you should find everything you need. You need a password field for your User, that should be clear.

> If you’d like to manually authenticate a user by comparing a
> plain-text password to the hashed password in the database, use the
> convenience function check_password(). It takes two mandatory
> arguments: the plain-text password to check, and the full value of a
> user’s password field in the database to check against. It returns
> True if they match, False otherwise.

It would work something like this: 
views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

[...]
plain_pw_from_post = form.cleaned_data.get(...)
hashed_pw_from_usermodel = User.objects.all().first().password

if check_password(plain_pw_from_post, hashed_pw_from_usermodel):
    # insert your login logic here
else:
    # login failed logic here
[...]
```

#### Edit after OP shared the code for his user-model:

Check out this: [Django's User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#fields)
Most likely you would want to inherit your custom user model from that model! That gives you a lot of functionality already. As you can see in the link it also already has a password. If you inherit your model from that you can also very easily utilize the `authenticate` function as described in another answer to your question.

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_role_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_avatar_path = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user_job_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_educ_qual = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_companies = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Replace email, username and password field since by inheriting from `AbstractUser` we already have those.

views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        posting_user = User.objects.get_or_404(username=request.POST['username'])
      #  if check_password(request.POST['password'], posting_user.password):
          
        user = authenticate(username=posting_user.username, password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

Read this for "normal" [django authentication](https://user%20=%20authenticate(username=%27john%27,%20password=%27secret%27)) of users.

Comment: I updated my answer but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: For sure it is not working because you are storing the plain password as a CharField in your users model. You should not do that. If you share the code for your user-model I can help you further.

Comment: I appreciate your answer it definitely helped me. I posted the correct code it's working as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the autenticate method to authenticate a user.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def user_login(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
    user_email = request.POST.get('user_email')
    user_password = request.POST.get('user_password')
    user_details = authenticate(request, email=user_email, password=user_password)
    
    if user_details is not None:
        request.session['logged_in'] = True
        request.session['user_email'] = user_details.email
        request.session['u_id'] = user_details.id
        request.session['user_name'] = user_details.username
        request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
else:
    return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JHS99    I already updated the code. Please have a check on it now.

Comment: still returning false, I'm not using Django built in models. I have my own model:     user_password = models.CharField(max_length=20), user_email = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

Comment: @JHS99  It should work now. please check updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts I got the code to work I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

fixed the code finally it's working I thought I'd share:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_password = request.POST['user_password']
        user_details = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).values()
        hashed_pw = User.objects.all().first().user_password
        check_password(user_password, hashed_pw)

        if user_details:
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['user_email'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['u_id'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['user_name'] = user_details[0]["user_name"]
            request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

Comment: This `User.objects.all().first()` grabs always the first User of all your objects. For sure you want to change that to some other logic. E g. `User.objects.get(username="JHS99", email=user_email")`

Comment: I don't see a difference can you clarify more?

Comment: Your function `user_login` gets data from POST. Based on that data you want to filter your database and grab the matching User from your database, e.g. the one with `username="Bob"`. Then you want to compare the password of Database-User-Bob with the entered password of POST. I just wanted to let you know that the `.first()` method is not grabbing a specific User matching to your POST-form-data. It is always pulling the first User the database has stored within all User-entries. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Comment: how do you suggest me to edit this? cause now the hashed pass + plain are both logging in

Comment: Please share the code of your model. Add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: just edited with user model